# What does this shorthand mean |x| = -x > 0

Tags: inequality

I’m currently reading a calculus book where some inequalities fundamentals is being discussed. All of a sudden some shorthand that I don’t understand shows up, namely:

|x| = -x > 0

I know that modulus of x is -x for any x less than 0. I also know what the greater than symbol means, but I can’t make sense of all of that put together in shorthand. What does it mean?

Is that simply a way of saying “IF -x > 0, THEN modulus of x is -x”? My question is really about the shorthand way of bunching the if/then in one go. To me it looks weird! How can you have an equals sign and a greater than symbol all in one statement!?

Comment: As you said, it means that $x<0$. Perhaps, the identity above can simplify the argument to show a given inequality.

Comment: I think more context is necessary to say exactly what the author meant. Otherwise, the notation just means that both are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard mathematical usage $a = b > c$ is a shorthand for "$a = b$ and $b > c$". It is a conjunction (AND) not a conditional (IF/THEN). This shorthand applies (within reason) to any meaningful combination of binary relations: e.g., you will see things like $x \in A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ to mean that $A$, $B$ and $C$ form a chain of sets (i.e., $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$) and that $x \in A$.

In your example, $|x| = -x > 0$ means that $|x|= -x$ and $-x > 0$. This conjunction happens to be true iff $x < 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve never seen this sort of conjunction before!

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that writing

$$\vert x \vert=-x \gt 0$$ is rather strange.

However $-x \gt 0$ is equivalent to $x \lt 0$ and we know that in that case $\vert x \vert =-x$.

But saying it explicitly would have been **much** better.

Comment: But how can you put that statement in English? How does one say it? How do I finish this sentence: “the modulus of x is...”

Comment: It isn't strange at all. $a = b > c$ is a standard shorthand.

Comment: @RobArthan What is particular here is that there is an implied logical relation. It is **because** $-x \gt 0$ that you have $\vert x \vert =-x$. This would have been better to say it explicitly from my point of view.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I think more context is needed to make that judgment. If the statement is preceded by something like "let $x < 0$, then ..." your observation doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute value (aka modulus) is the first piecewise defined function students usually encounter, and often the only one until years later.

$$|x| = \begin{cases}x & \text{if } x \geq 0\\-x & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases}$$

The statement $|x| = -x$ says that we are in the second case; $x$ is a negative number, i.e. $x < 0$.
Since $x < 0$, that means $-x > 0$.

That's a pretty awkward way to write it.

Comment: So was the shorthand basically saying: “when x is less than 0, the modulus of x equals -x”?

Comment: @Baba.S, I think it was specifically saying, "Right here" (I don't know the context) "$x < 0$."  What you said is part of the definition of modulus, which is probably presumed known.